# Unable to access global variable which is set in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have **mytheme-child/functions.php** where I declared and assigned global variable:

```
 global $mycustvar;
 $mycustvar = "abc"
```

Now when I `print_r()` same variable in `**mytheme-child/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php**` then not able to get output as **abc**. It should be right? As it's a global variable?.

Kindly correct me if I misunderstood somewhere.

Comment: mr.void is right, more specificly you have to define global $mycustvar again in product-image.php - this is just the way it works

Comment: where in function file do you assign your global variable?

Answer (score 1):

For example, in functions.php:

```
function test() {
    global $hello;
    $hello = 'hello world';
}

add_action('after_theme_setup', 'test');
```

In single.php, this will not work:

```
echo $hello;
```

Because $hello is undefined. This however will work:

```
global $hello;
echo $hello;
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
// function.php
function my_custom_data() {
    global $mycustvar;
    $mycustvar = 'abc';
}
add_action( 'after_theme_setup', 'my_custom_data' );
```

then call any where just as

```
global $mycustvar;
echo $mycustvar;
```